# Have a custom number pad in iOS to dial number

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I am making an app through which the user dials the number.I want to design my own number pad with delete button.I can make them easily by taking 10 buttons on the UIView and placing them accordingly and whenever the button presses i will have the button number updated in my dialer box.
I want to know whether my approach is good or there is something else through which i can achieve this in a better manner.

Comment: textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation; ?

Comment: Of course, you are good to go with creating your own custom numberpad unless you do not want to use the native one provided in the SDK. No problem.

Comment: @GenieWanted is my approach good to go?

Comment: Yes.. Should be fine.. I have seen a few apps that have their own custom keyboard implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using following 3 ways,

1. As comment given by @nerowolfe i.e. by using keyboardType equals to UIKeyboardTypePhonePad...
   You can get many keyboard type click [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_input_types_text_field.htm)
2. Using UIView with array of buttons inside it as you think.
3. If you are building this app for ipad then you should use popover instead of UIView or any custom vies. Using popover is more standard way than custom view for ipad. It gives benefits like,

   - Requires small space
   - Good look
   - Standard way

My suggestion to u is that if you are building app for iphone then option 1 or 2 is better and if you are building it for ipad option 3 is great...